# How to do a 2005 v6 Avalon Oil Pan Removal (Australian Model)

Tags: toyota, avalon, oil-pan

My mechanic has said that I need to clean the filter at the bottom of the block inside the oil pan as this is causing the oil light to come on (I can't afford to pay the mechanic to do that currently) and if not resolved will cause engine failure.

So my questions is how do I remove the oil pan and clean the filter myself or where is a video/instructions on how to achieve this at home.

I was also looking at purchasing the [TIS](https://techinfo.toyota.com/techInfoPortal/) subscription, would the manual there work for my engine? (ie: Global Engine)

Comment: Is your mechanic talking about the 'strainer' on the oil pickup in the sump? If that's clogged/blocked you might have other issues with deposits in the oil that cause low oil pressure...

Comment: @Timo - Yes that what he was referring to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I decided to just take the plunge and found out on my model that there is no issue with manifolds or air-conditioning pumps blocking access.

Here are the steps in-case other non-mechanical people need to perform the same thing:

1. Remove all the bolts and nuts
2. Pry the oil pan off using a screwdriver and hammer to lodge the screwdriver between pan and block
3. Twist the screwdriver to break the seal
4. Pull the pan of the block
5. Undo the 2 nuts and 1 bolt that hold the 'strainer' to the block
6. Clean, clean and clean!
7. Use sealant around the pan
8. Put Oil pan back on
9. Hand tighten bolts and wait 1 hour
10. Tighten the bolts and wait 24 hours to cure
11. Fill with oil